# Pubnub - Issue with history API

Tags: javascript, webrtc, pubnub

We are using Pubnub Webrtc API to make Webrtc video calls, and we have enabled "media playbackback options" in our Pubnub account.

We are able to make video calls successfully, but while accessing the history API, we are getting only snapshots and not the videos.

code for history API:

```
PHONE.history = function(settings) {
            pubnub.history({
                channel  : settings['number'],
                callback : function(call_history) {
                    settings['history'](call_history[0]);
                },
                count:10,
                reverse: true
            })
        };
```

any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: PubNub does not handle video/audio. PubNub is the *signal protocol* only with respect to WebRTC. And the property "media playbackback options" does not exist in PubNub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubnub takes care of signaling and not media.

If you want to handle media - things like recording, or running multiway calls, you'll need something else.

If the idea is to go for a managed service then try out Tokbox (https://tokbox.com/). If you want to go DIY then try Kurento (http://www.kurento.org).